# Can a carbon planet form within a silicate-based planetary system?

Tags: planets, space, earth-like, carbon-based

Can a carbon-rich planet form in a solar system where all the other planets have a lower carbon-to-oxygen ratio (like Earth has silicates and oxides, or oxygen and silica)? (Let’s say the planet formed locally — not a rogue planet that was captured.)

Can the primordial accretion disk have differentiated composition ring? Or are carbon-type planets only formed with carbon-rich star systems?

Comment: Earth is also not a carbon-type planet, there is very little carbon down here. its just that carbon tends to form chemical compounds that are volatile and float to the surface, while silicon makes compounds that are, well, rocks. And rocks don't float. not even tiny ones. *mostly* Earth is an Iron world, with tiny amounts of silicon-oxygen slag floating on it, and miniscule amounts of carbon and hydrogen sludge floating on top of the slag.

Comment: @PcMan: Well, MOST rocks don't float.  Meet pumice: https://www.universityofcalifornia.edu/news/solving-mystery-floating-rocks-pumice  And Earth is mostly a silicate world, with a relatively small iron/nickel core.  (V = 4/3πr^3, core radius 3483 km. Earth radius 6370 km, so the core is about 1/6 of the total volume.)

Comment: @jamesqf Earth: 5.98e24kg.. Iron=32%, oxygen=30.1%,silicon-15.1%.. I'm not sure I would consider 32% of the whole thing as "a relatively small iron core". and I **definitely** would not call it by its third-most abundant element. That would be like saying the ocean is composed of pure chlorine.

Comment: @PcMan: We're talking about two different things, I think, as your figures seem to be for mass, while I was calculating volume.  The mostly-iron core is relatively small, since iron is quite a bit denser than the other major constituents.  The "silicon-oxygen slag" also contains quite a bit of iron (and other stuff), and occupies a far larger volume.

Comment: @jamesqf Defining an object's composition by *volume* is a daft idea! Using that rule, a boeing 747 is made out of "air".

Comment: @PcMan: By that logic, you could define a 747 as mostly organic - fuel, passengers, &c.  if the Earth were a small core surrounded by a large atmosphere, then it too would be mostly air, just as the gas giants are mostly hydrogen & helium.

Comment: @jamesqf A gas giant is mostly hydrogen and helium because 98% of their mass is hydrogen and helium. The Earth is mostly iron because that is the main element it is composed of. with oxygen a close second, and silicon a distant third. I know this,. *you* know this. I really struggle to understand your agenda is denying this ***FACT***? There is nothing of opinion in it, it is not subjective, it is merely how the universe is. I honestly do not understand your antagonism here?

Comment: can a mod please take this to chat for me, i seem unable to. And this sort of nonsense should not be visible to the viewing public.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is possible that the composition of the original accretion disk is not homogeneous with respect to species types.

Once the star begins blowing off its radiation and stellar wind, this will tend to blow away the atoms in the accretion disk. Because of their different masses, lighter atoms will be blown away faster than heavier ones.

However the difference in atomic weight between carbon (12) and silicon (14) is rather low, so this separation mechanism won't be very effective in separating them, as much as it can be with respect to separating for example helium and hydrogen from iron.

Comment: My interpretation of this is that carbon planets would need to form farther out, and if they're needed closer to the star, migrate inward somehow. Is that on the right track?

Comment: Thanks for all  your input! It really help! And Merry Christmas!